# Algorithm to assemble a simplified jigsaw puzzle where all edges are identified

Tags: c++, algorithm

Are there any kind of algorithms out there that can assist and accelerate in the construction of a jigsaw puzzle where the edges are already identified and each edge is guaranteed to fit exactly one other edge (or no edges if that piece is a corner or border piece)?

I've got a data set here that is roughly represented by the following structure:

```
struct tile {
    int a, b, c, d;
};

tile[SOME_LARGE_NUMBER] = ...;
```

Each side (a, b, c, and d) is uniquely indexed within the puzzle so that only one other tile will match an edge (if that edge has a match, since corner and border tiles might not).

Unfortunately there are no guarantees past that. The order of the tiles within the array is random, the only guarantee is that they're indexed from 0 to SOME_LARGE_NUMBER. Likewise, the side UIDs are randomized as well. They all fall within a contiguous range (where the max of that range depends on the number of tiles and the dimensions of the completed puzzle), but that's about it.

I'm trying to assemble the puzzle in the most efficient way possible, so that I can ultimately address the completed puzzle using rows and columns through a two dimensional array. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tile[]` data defines an undirected graph where each node links with 2, 3 or 4 other nodes. Choose a node with just 2 links and set that as your origin. The two links from this node define your X and Y axes. If you follow, say, the X axis link, you will arrive at a node with 3 links — one pointing back to the origin, and two others corresponding to the positive X and Y directions. You can easily identify the link in the X direction, because it will take you to another node with 3 links (not 4).

In this way you can easily find all the pieces along one side until you reach the far corner, which only has two links. Of all the pieces found so far, the only untested links are pointing in the Y direction. This makes it easy to place the next row of pieces. Simply continue until all the pieces have been placed.

Answer (score -1):

This might be not what you are looking for, but because you asked for *"most efficient way possible"*, here is a relatively recent scientific solution.

Puzzles are a complex combinatorial problem ([NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)) and require some help from Academia to solve them efficiently. State of the art algorithms was recently beaten by [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Depending on your puzzle sizes (and desire to study scientific stuff ;)) you might be interested in this paper: [A Genetic Algorithm-Based Solver for Very Large Jigsaw Puzzles](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=jigsaw+puzzle+genetic+algorithm&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) . GAs would work around in surprising ways some of the problems you encounter in classic algorithms.

Note that [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) are [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), so there is a straightforward way to do calculations on parallel machines, such as multi-core CPUs, GPUs (CUDA/OpenCL) and even distributed/cloud frameworks. Which makes them hundreds to thousands times faster. GPU-accelerated GAs unlock puzzle sizes unavailable for conventional algorithms.

Comment: Jigsaw puzzles are only NP-complete if the edges have multiple matches, which here they don't. It's not even a hard problem here, the edges force a specific order that you could find greedily just placing pieces where they will fit (which is by definition their one and only proper position)